# Negative Number inside an arccos or arcsin function

Tags: trigonometry

I am trying to solve $\tan(\arccos(-5/8))$. I thought that $\cos(-x)$ is the same as $\cos(x)$, so I got a positive answer, $\sqrt{39}/5$. But when I looked up the answer it said it was $-\sqrt{39}/5$. Why is it negative?

Comment: A trick  $\sin (\arccos X)$ is always positive.  $\arccos$ is always in first or second quandrant and the $\sin$ of anything in the first or third is always positive.  And $\cos(\arcsin x)$ is always positive.  $\arcsin$ is always in the first or fourth quadrant and $\cos$ of anything int first of fourth quadrant is always positive.  And $sin(\arcsin x) = x$ and $\cos(\arccos x) = x$ so $\tan (\arccos (x)) = \frac {\sin (arcos x)}{\cos(\arccos  x)} =\frac {+\sqrt{1- x^2}}{x}$.  And as $x$ is negative....

Comment: Also note that $\sin(\arcsin x) = x$ be definition gut $\arcsin(\sin \theta)=\pm x = |x|$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1224415/how-do-i-prove-that-arccosx-arccos-x-pi-when-x-in-1-1

Answer (score 2):

Trig functions are not injective.  If $\cos x = \cos y$ it is not the case that $x = y$.  So if we define $\arccos k$ is the angle $\theta$ so that $\cos \theta = k$, then we have to ask *which* angle $\theta$ so that $\cos \theta = k$.  There are an infinite number of such angles. And there are *two* different such angles between $0$ and $2\pi$.   Which one do we choose for $\arccos$?

We have to choose one and not the other.  Which one do we choose?

The answer is completely arbitrary.  But it is consistant.

If $M > 0$ and $\cos \theta = M$ then either $\theta$ is in the first quadrant $0\le \theta \le \frac {\pi}2$, or $\theta$ is in the fourth quadrat $\frac {3\pi}2 \le \theta \le 2\pi$.  Which one is the answer to $\arccos M$?

The answer is... the one in the first quadrant.  Why do we choose that one and not the one in the fourth quadrant?  "Because" that's why.  I'd say we flipped a coin but we had to pick one and ... the positive value would make things easier.

And likewise if $M < 0$ and $\cos \theta =M$ then either $\theta$ is in the second or third quadrant.  Which one is $\arccos M$?  The one in the third quadrant.

Arbitrarily:  $0 \le \arccos M \le \pi$.  And $-\frac {\pi}2 \le \arcsin M \le \frac {\pi}2$.

That's just convention.

....

So

We have $\arcsin(-\frac 58) = \theta$.  We have $\cos \theta = -\frac 58<0$.  There are two possible values for $\theta$ where that is true.  One is between $\frac \pi 2$ and $\pi$, and the other between $\pi$ and $\frac {3\pi}2$.  We choose the one that is between $0$ and $\pi$ so that is the one between $\frac {\pi}2$ and $\pi$.  Why that one?  "Because".

And if $\frac {\pi}2 \le \theta \le \pi$, then we know that $\sin \theta > 0$.

Notice *IF* we had choose then *other* possible value then we would have had $\sin \theta < 0$.

But we always have $0 \le \arccos \le \pi$ and we never have $\pi < \arccos < 2\pi$.  So we *didn't* pick it.

So $\cos \theta = -\frac 58$.

Then $\sin \theta = \pm \sqrt{1- (\frac 58)^2} =\pm \frac {\sqrt{39}}8$.  But because $\arccos -\frac 58\le \pi$ we have $\sin \theta > 0$.

So $\sin(arccos(-\frac 58)) = \frac {\sqrt{39}}8$.

And $\tan (\arccos(-\frac 58)) = \frac {\sin(\arccos(-\frac 58))}{\sin(\arccos(-\frac 58))}=\frac {\frac {\sqrt{39}}8}{-\frac 58}=-\frac {\sqrt{39}}5$

Answer (score 1):

Note,

$$\arccos (-\frac58) = \pi - \arccos (\frac58)$$

Thus,

$$\tan(\arccos (-\frac58)) =\tan(\pi - \arccos(\frac58))
=- \tan(\arccos (\frac58))=-\tan(\arctan\frac{\sqrt{39}}5)=-\frac{\sqrt{39}}5$$

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to look at the ratio. It is negative, so the angle formed by -5 and 8 is in the second or fourth quadrant. What is tangent of any angle in these two quadrants? Negative. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. So it just depends on the quadrant?

Comment: Yes, having a geometric picture in mind helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

$$\tan(\arccos(-x))=\tan(\pi/2-\arcsin(-x))=\tan(\pi/2+\arcsin x)=-\cot(\arcsin x)$$

Now if $\arcsin x=y,x=\sin y$ and using [Principal Value of Inverse Trig Function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67291/principal-value-of-inverse-trig-function)

$\cos y=+\sqrt{1-x^2}$

$\cot(\arcsin x)=\cot y=?$